# eclipse cannot find the jar available in maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have a pom.xml with the following entry

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

And on maven install the jar is added to the maven repository and is also listed in the maven dependencies library.

But I am not able to import any of the classes from the added jar 'spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar' for the particular entry, though it shows in the classpath

The error - in eclipse "cannot be resolved to a type"

environment - maven 3.1 and Spring tool suite

Thanks

Comment: We'd need far more info to determine the issue.  Are you using M2Eclipse or the Apache Maven Eclipse plugin?  Did you set up the Maven nature in your project?  etc.

Comment: Yes it is a maven project, and it is a Spring tool suite which has inbuilt maven plugin i guess. BTW the maven clean install is working.

Comment: just want to confirm which IDE you are using eclipse or SpringToolSuite?

Answer (score 1):

Solved - found the solution through some other forum

The jar inside the repository was corrupted.

After clearing the .m2 folder in the physical drive and repeating the maven clean install worked.

Thanks for the time @techidiot @jtravaglini.